# Delete Specific Rows in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a fairly large 2x2 matrix containing date and temperatures. There is a cluster of NaNs and incorrect data. I used `find` to get the index that contains the incorrect data. These indexes are stored in another variable. How do i remove the rows (date and value) corresponding to the indices?
Thanks.

Comment: An example would make this clearer - please include a sample of the code you've already written. Also, how is your matrix large if it's only 2x2?

Answer (score 5):

`fairly large 2x2 matrix` makes little or no sense.

This is part from MATLAB documentation

You can delete rows and columns from a matrix by assigning the empty array [] to those rows or columns. Start with

```
A = magic(4)
A =
    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1
```

Then, delete the second column of A using

```
A(:, 2) = []
```

This changes matrix A to

```
A = 
   16    3   13
    5   10    8
    9    6   12
    4   15    1
```

Also you can delete multiple rows/columns at once:

```
A([1 3],:)=[]
A =
    5    10     8
    4    15     1
```