# Remove all rows after a certain value in matlab matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a MATLAB matrix that is 100,000x2 (100,000 rows, two columns)

How do I remove all the rows after row number 47,526?

In other words, I want to truncate the 100,000x2 matrix into a 47526x2 matrix

Comment: You can assign a new matrix to the rows you want using the `:` operator

Comment: Have you read https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html, particularly https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete Specific Rows in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227141/delete-specific-rows-in-matlab)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your matrix is named `A`:

```
A = A(1:47526, :);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
YourMatrix(47527:end,:) = [] ;
```